# When to start loading data in VM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Let's say I have a page with two buttons and a content control. I also have a View-Model defined for this page. When I press each button a specific view-model is bound to a content control, so buttons are used to switch between views. The problem is, when view is switched some data needs to be downloaded (doesn't matter from where, it could be a database) via a view-model - and I don't really have an idea where to put code responsible for that (i.e., code that starts downloading data). Is constructor a good place for it?

Comment: Why cant you just have a function Populate() in the view model all call that to download data?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the ViewModels have a specific method (mostly called `Init`), that performs data initialization. Constructor should not be used for these purposes, because it should just construct the object, nothing else. Moreover - you will probably want to perform data loading asynchronously, so constructor is again not very well suited for this.

The `Init` method should be called just when the navigation is performed, so you can pass your navigation parameters to it.